# Is there a definitive way to determine the positive and negative leads of a laser diode?

Tags: pcb, circuit-analysis, laser

I am trying to use a laser diode that I pulled out of a laser printer, but the circuit board doesn't have the ground and power leads of the diode labeled. I can't find any diagrams of the circuitry or of the specific diode online. Is there a way to find the positive and negative leads without risking breaking anything?

If there is any other information needed I will try and supply it upon request.

Comment: Usually the term diode implies that it conducts in one direction much better than in another

Comment: they burn out very fast if reversed, but may have CC regulator built in

Comment: Re-using old laser diodes from "other" equipment is troublesome. Risk of breaking your eyes is something to factor in.

Comment: Can't you do a continuity check between ground and the points where you pulled it from the circuit board?

Comment: In theory, you could do this circuit : voltage source -> resistor (to limit current) -> diode -> ground. Measure voltage at diode for either direction. In one direction, you will measure the forward voltage of the diode and the other, the voltage source voltage since the diode blocks the current in reverse. You will be able to identify the polarity of the diode this way.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I am aware, that is why I am trying to find out if there is a way to determine which direction I should be connecting it. Reading back, might "leads" be the wrong word?

Answer (score 3):

The only sure and safe way is the data sheet, but that sounds out of the question.

First off, be careful.  Laser diodes, even without collimation optics can generate enough light to damage your eyes, and the ones you find in a lot of electronics are either infra-red or very deep red that is barely visible.  This means they can be generating damaging light without you realizing it.  In my opinion, the most dangerous lasers are the ones in the 700-800 nm region, which you may be able to see as a *very* faint red, which can be dangerously misleading.

That said, how many pins does it have?  Many laser diodes have a built-in photo diode as well for measuring and feeding back the output power. Sometimes they have 4 pins, but more often 3, with a common cathode or common anode, or with the cathode of one connected to the anode of the other.

You can work out the pinout using standard diode testing techniques, but you have to be careful.  Laser diodes are very delicate.  The reverse breakdown voltage is usually only a few volts, while excessive forward current can instantly damage the output facet, turning your nice laser into a crummy LED.  A standard multi-meter diode tester can destroy a laser diode.  So you want to make sure your test circuit limits both the voltage and current to safe values, and be careful of ESD.  It is common in laboratory use for laser diode drivers/mounts to use a relay to short the pins together until everything is connected and powered up to make sure that no turn-on transient drives too much current through the diode.

In a 3 pin laser, the photodiode will be a standard silicon diode with a forward voltage drop of around 0.7 volts.  The laser diode will have a forward voltage drop that depends on wavelength, and will generally be around 1.5-2 volts for red and near IR lasers, up to 3-4 volts for blue lasers.

Answer (score 2):

Try with small current up to 3 - 5 mA for two polarization. Such current not destroy your LD but this allow you to see weak lighting of the diode for one of the polarization wchich is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try the diode function on digital multimeter if you have one. It should show some numbers if you connect the probes in forward bias (for usual diode the number is usually somewhere around .700), if it doesn't show you any numbers then you connected the probes in reverse bias and the number will be 1 or 0 (depends of DMM) because in reverse bias there is a lot of impedance an so forth not much conduction.

That should do it.

Comment: The diode functionality of a lot of meters doesn't go high enough for a lot of LED or Laser diodes which need 3V or more.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: LED diode starts conducting at .7 Volts . And Laser diode probably the same so if you connect it in forward bias on multimeter it should show you "knee voltage" which is around .7 Volts.

Comment: multimeters measure the voltage drop over a certain current, often 1mA or 100µA, which for such diodes often results in voltages of over 3V which lots of multimeters will not measure/display

Comment: Yep! Heed what @PlasmaHH said. Most DMMs on diode function act as current sources with very limited compliance. Many cannot reach 4V (so they cannot test some kind of white and blue LEDs, for example). I don't know the usual threshold voltage for LASER diodes, but if it is substantially higher than 3V, a test with a DMM could be inconclusive

Comment: If the OP has a DMM, might as well give it a try, though.